# An extra empty progress bar is formed, why?

Tags: r, progress-bar

I have developed multiple functions that perform a specific task overall. Each function starts by printing a text and then uses a progress bar. There is one empty progress bar after executing the first function. I have checked the consistency of `txtProgressBar`, `getTxtProgressBar` and `close` for every function. They seem to be correct. What might cause the problem?

```
[1] "*** Obtaining the requested data for test ***"
  |================================================================| 100%
  |                                                                |   0%[1]
"*** Performing the requested statistical analyses for test ***"
  |================================================================| 100%
[1] "*** Preparing the requested heatmaps for test ***"
  |================================================================| 100%
[1] "*** Preparing the requested excel file(s) for test ***"
  |================================================================| 100%
```

Comment: What might cause the problem? I'd say it's the code that causes that to happen.  It's hard to say which code that is without seeing yours though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason myself. In the second function, the `print` function was mistakenly placed between `txtProgressBar` and `getTxtProgressBar`.